# Fetching data from a horisontal rows to a vertical column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in a tab (tab named hours) where the data i allocated on a row cells F72:X72 and then also on more rows of course but lets take this as an example.
I need to add this data with link to a different tab (tab named team) where the data needs to be in a column, in my example column cells S15:S33.

I know I can transpose data when copying it but it doesn't work when pasting the links. I have read a lot of similar issues and solutions but nothing works.

Can you please help? is there a formula for this?

Worth to note that this is a large document with many formulas.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027) function is here for.

In the leftmost cell of your destination (`S15` in the example) enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(F72:X72)
```

Or add the full range of rows in the same way to transpose them to columns:

```
=TRANSPOSE(F72:X82)
```

*Note: This is an array formula. If you have a current version of Microsoft Office (Microsoft 365), then you can input the formula in the top-left-cell of the output range, then press ENTER (like with any regular formula) to confirm the formula as a dynamic array formula.*

If you have older/other versions of Excel (which do not support the newer *dynamic array formula*), the formula must be entered as a legacy array formula by **first selecting the output range** (`S15:S33` in the example), **input the formula in the top-left-cell of the output range, then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to confirm it. Excel inserts curly brackets at the beginning and end of the formula for you.

Comment: Many thanks!

This isn't working though, I seem to have an older version so I needed to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. But what it does it gives me the value and link for F72 in S15 but when I then drag the formula down on the next row I get F73 and so on..

Comment: An array formula you're not supposed to drag, it spills over by itself to output the whole range you entered in the leftmost cell.

Comment: So what version of Excel do you have? What was the formula you entered in `S15`? After confirming with Ctrl+Shift+Enter did it automatically add curly brackets around the formula?

Comment: Hi, yes it added the brackets but didnt spill. 
I added the formula to S15.
Version 2303

Comment: 2303 but which year and build? (2303 seems to be a pretty up to date version)

Comment: @IdaHassel I found the issue... I haven't used legacy array formulas in a while, so didn't realize that you need to select the output range first (see updated instructions)

Comment: Woooow! Thank you, now it worked!

I actually tried this but didnt get how i would input the formula at the top but now I did it.

Comment: Great. If my answer answered your question, consider marking it as [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer.